# Difference of the reciprocal of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any two natural numbers $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ is $\frac{1}{n^2} -\frac{1}{m^2}$ unique? In other words: is there a solution of four different natural numbers n,m,o,p that satisfy $$\frac{1}{n^2} -\frac{1}{m^2} = \frac{1}{o^2} -\frac{1}{p^2}$$ ?

Comment: Whenever you see squares of numbers, you should think of $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2.$ Resolve the denominators by multiplication and apply the formula. Hint: What will you get e.g. out of $16 \cdot 24$?